# How do you concatenate elements from a string split?

Tags: python

Really simple question but I am struggling with this...If I have a file name called "first_second_third_fourth.txt" and I want to keep the first few elements of that string when creating a new file, I usually run something like this:

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
new_name = file.split("_")[0] + "_newfile.txt"
```

The output would just be `first_newfile.txt`

But if I want to somehow get a new file called `first_second_newfile.txt` I cannot come up with a simple solution to write it out in one line.

I tried:

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
new_name = file.split("_")[0:1] + "_newfile.txt"
```

But this throws an error because you cannot concatenate a string to a list. And the only way I manage is to split it up but this seems so messy:

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
new_name = file.split("_")[0] + file.split("_")[1] + "_newfile.txt"
```

I am just curious if there is a shorter way to grab the two elements in the split list without having that second iteration of `file.split("_")[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.join()` to create desired file name:

```
f = "first_second_third_fourth.txt"
'_'.join(f.split('_')[0:2]) + '.txt
```

Output:

```
'first_second.txt'
```

Comment: Oh yes join! Don't know why I didn't think of that...yes that worked nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...